# "No required driver detected for unity" on Dell Mini 1010

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook, intel-graphics, dell-mini-10

I want to "try" ubuntu-netbook off the livecd on my Dell Mini1010 (Poulsbo Intel GMA 500 graphics card). It tells me that there is:

```
"No required driver detected for unity.

You will need to choose the Ubuntu Desktop session once you select your user name.
If you are on Ubuntu live CD, the username is "ubuntu" and you have to enter a blank password."
```

I intend to install UNE Maverick on my Mini 1010 but I want Unity to function properly. Does this directly reflect what will occur if I install it? Is there a way to correct this issue? (what drivers do i need?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GMA500 (codename: Poulsbo) chipset is the main Intel graphics card without open-source drivers¹.  As such, we can't support them on the LiveCD, and these drivers are consistently problematic and are hence not available in the official Ubuntu archives.

Sadly your card has poor Linux support.  You can try the drivers linked to from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7071/no-required-driver-detected-for-unity-on-dell-mini-1010/7073#7073), but Ubuntu is not in a position to support this hardware.

¹: For various convoluted and interesting reasons :)

Answer (score 4):

Your graphics card seems to be under the minimal requirements for Unity - as per [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements).

However, try this. Install UNR (on the HDD). Install [this driver](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo/) (it has 3D support), then restart and see if Unity works. If that does not work, then you are out of luck. GMA500 is a crappy little chipset.

Comment: I get the white top panel with wallpaper and icons on the side that don't render properly. The icons rollover labels work. GMA500 is pretty bad.

Comment: Can you detail how exactly does one install "this driver", and gets 3D support from it.